# Get data from USB using Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, usb, libusb

I am not understanding the USB protocol properly and so getting confused with my code to get data about the USB when I add it. I can't figure out where I am going wrong. My system is Windows 8 64 bit.

There is a major error with which I need help as well.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
# Find our device
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
busses = usb.busses()
# Was it found?
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

for bus in busses:
    devices = bus.devices
    for dev in devices:
        try:
            _name = usb.util.get_string(dev.dev, 19, 1)
        except:
             continue
        dev.set_configuration()
        cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
        interface_number = cfg[(0,0)].bInterfaceNumber
        alternate_settting = usb.control.get_interface(interface_number)
        print "Device name:",_name
        print "Device:", dev.filename
        print "  idVendor:",hex(dev.idVendor)
        print "  idProduct:",hex(dev.idProduct)
        for config in dev.configurations:
            print "  Configuration:", config.value
            print "    Total length:", config.totalLength 
            print "    selfPowered:", config.selfPowered
            print "    remoteWakeup:", config.remoteWakeup
            print "    maxPower:", config.maxPower
        print
```

This is the error I get:

> import usb.backend.libusb10 as libusb10 
>   ImportError: No module named backend.libusb10

Comment: Which version of pyusb are you using? Have you tried with the [latest version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyusb/files/PyUSB%201.0/1.0.0-alpha-3/)? Note that there are API differences between libusb 0.x and 1.0.

Comment: i am using libusb 1.0

Comment: Try updating pyusb to the [latest version from github](https://github.com/walac/pyusb). Its seems some filenames have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Except latest version of [pyusb](https://github.com/walac/pyusb) is also necessary to have installed latest version of [libusb](http://libusbx.org/).

On windows just extract from package of libusb file: `libusb-1.0.dll` (from folder MinGW32/64 - depends on python version) and copy it into `C:\Windows\System32\` folder.